# subclassing a class implementing MKMapViewDelegate but MKMapViewDelegate method not called

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

i am subClassing a class which implements a `MKMapViewDelegate`.I am also setting the delegate in the super class but my  `-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation` method is not called. Here is my code

My superClass code

```
 //  RecentPhotosMapViewController.h
 @interface RecentPhotosMapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>

     @property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *annotations;
     @property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end


 //  RecentPhotosMapViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad{

      [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // load annotation data



       self.mapView.delegate = self;
}

  - (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:    (id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{

MKAnnotationView *aView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"MapVC"];

     // safety code
     if(!aView){
         aView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"MapVC"];
         aView.canShowCallout = YES;
         aView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
         aView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

      }
     aView.annotation = annotation;
    [(UIImageView *)aView.leftCalloutAccessoryView setImage:nil];

    return aView;
}
```

my subclass code

```
     //  RecentPhotosMapViewControllerWithAnnotationData.h
     @interface RecentPhotosMapViewControllerWithAnnotationData : RecentPhotosMapViewController
     @end
```

RecentPhotosMapViewControllerWithAnnotationData.m file

```
      -(void) viewDidLoad{


// extract annotation data.....
// set zoom level


[super viewDidLoad];

}
```

However `-(void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view method is called`

Any Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try moving `[super viewDidLoad];` as the first line in `viewDidLoad` in the subclass.

By the time you call `[super viewDidLoad]` which sets the delegate, everything has already happened.

Comment: thanks it helped but first i need to do set up my modal before my [super viewDidLoad] is called in my subclass any other suggestion.

Comment: You may want to reconsider why you are doing that, but you can move some stuff before the `[super viewDidLoad];` but keep in mind that there may be a better way of doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the mapView delegate assignment line as last line of your derived class viewDidLoad method:

RecentPhotosMapViewControllerWithAnnotationData.m

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{

// extract annotation data.....
// set zoom level

[super viewDidLoad];

self.mapView.delegate = self;

}
```